# Pandas Style to Excel using xlsxwriter as engine

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to return background color and font size but it only works when I return only one value, what's wrong in my code ?

this one wont work, I get this error :

```
""" Format cells in Excel file and output to screen if on windows"""
color = 'red' if '>' in str(val) else 'lightgray'
font_size = '45px'
return f'font-size: {font_size} ,background-color: {color}'
```

but if I return only one it works either fontsize or color

```
""" Format cells in Excel file and output to screen if on windows"""
color = 'red' if '>' in str(val) else 'lightgray'
font_size = '45px'
return f'font-size: {font_size}'
```

Thanks for your help in advanced Dini

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am calling the function when saving data.  I need to change font and background color. ``` with pd.ExcelWriter(file3, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
                self.data_differ_changed.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Changed', 
                freeze_panes=(1, 1))
                self.data_differ_new.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='New', freeze_panes=(1, 
                1))

                self.data_differ_changed.style.applymap(highlight_cells).to_excel(writer, 
                sheet_name='Changed')```

Comment: Can you add the error to your question?

Comment: I finally solved it, needed to use a ; instead of a , . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use ; instead of ,(comma) to pass as many paramters as I want.

```
""" Format cells in Excel file and output to screen if on windows"""
color = 'red' if '>' in str(val) else 'lightgray'
font_size = '45px'
return f'font-size: {font_size} ; background-color: {color}'
```